# Can an Apple Watch Companion App programmatically change Apple Watch background/watch face?

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch

Title sums it up pretty well. For example, would it be possible to develop an application where I can select an image on my iPhone and then have my Apple Watch's background color change to that image automatically?

I have tried researching for APIs that directly correlate to the Apple Watch's background / background color but have not found anything